# Do I need to add synchronization to this code?

Tags: c, windows

I am writing some code to perform explicit linking to a DLL. This code is offered to my users as an alternative to implicit linking with a .lib file. At the moment my planned code looks like this:

```
void DisableModule(int Module)
{
    typedef void (*DisableModuleProc)(int);
    static DisableModuleProc proc = NULL;
    if (proc == NULL)
        proc = (DisableModuleProc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "DisableModule");
    proc(Module);
}
```

There are lots of functions of this form, and I have excised the error checking for the purpose of this question.

My problem concerns thread safety. This function could potentially be called simultaneously from multiple threads. Clearly there is a race on the static variable `_DisableModule`. My belief is that because `_DisableModule` will be aligned on machine word boundary (either 32 or 64 bit boundary depending on target), that no tearing can occur and so the race is benign. It's possible that `GetProcAddress` will be called more times than necessary, but I do not believe that affects correctness of the program.

Is my analysis correct?

Comment: Is the called function (_DisableModule) itself threadsafe? Also, identifiers beginning with underscore and capital letter are reserved.

Comment: @zvrba Yes, the imported function is threadsafe.  Thanks a lot for the advice regarding reserved identifiers. I am not fluent in C at all.

Comment: Depends on the processor type, but on x86 or x64 this will work just fine.  Not so sure about ARM, it has a weak memory model.  Always wise to invoke 'better safe than sorry' when using threads.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think weak/strong memory model matters, or does it? I don't mind about re-ordering of reads and writes, just so long as there is no tearing. But I confess to knowing nothing about ARM. For what it is worth, I don't see this code running on anything other than x86 and x64 for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is perfectly safe on x86 and amd64.
At worst `GetProcAddress` is called several times.

On other architectures there may be problems with partial writes being interrupted. To circumvent this, you could use atomics (`InterlockedComparExchange` ...), but this is superfluous here.

Comment: So you are saying that with some architectures, machine word sized aligned writes are not atomic with respect to reads?

Comment: Aehm, there are architectures where pointers are not word sized ... (e.g. 16 bit arch, with 32-bit (far) pointers) or where writes on unaligned addresses are allowed, but may not be atomic on cacheline boundaries ... . But you cannot run windows on them ... .

Answer (score 0):

A simple lock should do it.
You should take the lock only if `proc==NULL`, so after a while it would never be taken. So contention isn't an issue.
You can call `GetProcAddress` with the lock held, or without it.

Option 1:

```
if (proc == NULL) {
    lock();
    proc = (DisableModuleProc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "DisableModule");
    unlock();
}
```

option 2:

```
if (proc == NULL) {
    DisableModuleProc tmp = (DisableModuleProc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "DisableModule");
    lock();
    if (proc == NULL) {
        proc = tmp;
    } else {
        // Any free needed?
    }
    unlock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm trying to avoid the need for locks.

Comment: If `GetProcAddress` is thread-safe, and always returns the same, then you're indeed fine. But the lock costs almost nothing the way I suggested.

Comment: It is threadsafe. But if it wasn't then your option 2 would fail.

Comment: That's why there were two options.